# addHTMLImage not working

Tags: php, html, email, pear, mime-mail

I am working on a project that sends out HTML emails to people after a forum is filled out, I have gotten the HTML portion of the code to work but for some reason cannot get the banner image to appear at the top when embedding the image into my code. I had it work before when I was working on the latest version of PHP but had to downgrade to PHP 5.3 in order for my scripts to run on our server. Since then I used the same code and it resulted in failure. I have tried many different methods and none have proven effective. Here is my code

```
    require_once('Mail.php');
    require_once('Mail/mime.php');

    $smtp_credentials = array('host' => 'smtp.postmarkapp.com', 'port' => 25, 'auth' =>          TRUE, 'username' => '*', 'password' => '*'); 

    $headers = array('From' => '*', 'To' => $email, 'Subject' => $subject);

    $mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => PHP_EOL));

    $file = '/*/*/*/dls.jpg';
    $mime->addHTMLImage(file_get_contents($file),'image/jpeg',basename($file),false, "blackstone");                   

    #I used this code to fish out the cid out of mime I tried echoing this out and 
    # it returned blackstone which I defined as the 5th parameter of addHTMLImage which
    # sets the cid. 
    $cid=$mime->_html_images[count($mime->_html_images)-1]['cid'];

    $banner = '<span style="color:#1f497d">
    <img width = "623" height = "85" src = "cid:' . $cid . '" />
    </span>';

    $message_text = $banner;

    $mime->setHTMLBody($message_text);

    $mime->setTXTBody($body_text);

    $mail = Mail::factory('smtp', $smtp_credentials);

    try {
    $send = $mail->send($email, $mime->headers($headers), $mime->get());

    } catch (Exception $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage(); die;
    }

    echo 'mail sent!';
```

I have tried many different things, like not using cids at all which I would prefer since a lot of mail clients do not work well with cids, but on the PEAR manual it is suggested to use cid in the src attribute. I am using gmail, but I do not think this is the problem since it worked when I was running the newer version of php. whenever I open the email, the html portion of it works. Where the image should be there is a little image icon but no image is displayed.

Comment: have you tried using a hard path to an image on your server?

Comment: also this is concerning `$file = '/*/*/*/dls.jpg';` I hope this is just censoring. Have you verified your path actually links to your image? Also it is recommended to use `mime_content_type($file)` for your mime instead of hard coding it.

Comment: $file is just censoring, Thank you for the response. When sent, the image does not appear in the email, but appears as an attachment at the bottom. I inspected the element in gmail and found the url, and changed my code to reference it like this

        <img src = "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/?       ui=2&ik=20babf7450&view=att&th=13cda213a4806f3e&attid=0.1&disp=thd&zw" width = "623" height = "85" alt = "pic.jpg"/>

I have had a strange success with this, and it even works on different mail clients such as aol. I am almost postive this is a bad way to do it though.

Comment: that you are, because that is a static link to a single image on the google server. the only reason you can access it via other mail clients is because a) that copy exists in your inbox, b) you are logged in and have privileges to view it.

Comment: what does the "src" for the image show up as in the actual email html?

Comment: <img src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/?                       ui=2&amp;ik=20babf7450&amp;view=att&amp;th=13cda213a4806f3e&amp;attid=        0.1&amp;disp=thd&amp;zw" width="623" height="85" alt="pic.jpg">

You were right If i log out of my gmail the image does not work in other clients, I figured this was not the correct way to do it but I have been getting desperate, I think I may just end up uploading the image onto our server and reference the url to that image. However I am not exactly sure how to do this.

Comment: say your site was www.mysite.com and you put the images in a subfolder called 'emailcontent' and your image was called 'banner.jpg' you would get the following `<img src="http://www.mysite.com/emailcontent/banner.jpg" />`

Comment: the image url is supposed to be an **absolute url**.. not a path (relative or absolute).. **it can't be a path**, it must be a complete url to the image.

Answer (score -1):

The image url is supposed to be an **absolute url**.. not a path (relative or absolute).. it can't be a path, it must be a complete url to the image.

So you need to use a valid url such as the one below.

`http://www.example.com/images/image-name.jpg`

Something like the below would not work.

`../path/to/images/image-name.jpg`

and the same goes for below (it won't work):

`/root/public/path/to/images/image-name.jpg`

so make sure you are specifying a valid url to your image.

Comment: using an absolute url would entail me uploading the image to a server and then referencing the url in the img src code. I thought about this as it would be a simple solution to a problem I have been struggling with for some time. I have read online that this is unsafe to do and leaves your server vulnerable. Is this true? is there a safe way to do this? Thank you for the help!

Comment: @JohnJosephAnthonyFlynn - to be honest, I have no idea about that.. and its the first time i'm hearing of that. Also, i have never been able to make anything but absolute URL's work, I came to the conclusion that it was the standard way and have stuck with that for the past few years without encountering any sorts of issues.

Comment: @JohnJosephAnthonyFlynn - continuing here (due to space)...
But all in all, i don't think you are uploading the image to a separate server with an absolute URI. As far as i can tell you are directly linking to that image in the email, so for instance if after sending the email you removed the image, the email would also not show the image as its directly using the image from your server/website.

Comment: @JohnJosephAnthonyFlynn - to upload an image directly in the email, i think you would have to use attachments.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I am going to use an absolute path. addHTMLImage attaches is for you and allows you to reference it without having to upload it onto a server. I got it working in the newer versions of php but not in this one. Thanks a lot for the response! and in order to use it do I still need to use the addHTMLImage? or can I just do something like <img src = "http://www.example.com/images/image-name.jp"/> without using the addHTMLImage?